# How to merge layers with different shapes?

Tags: python-2.7, tensorflow, keras

I 'm using Keras with tensorflow backend. I want to merge two layers with different shapes. I have a layer with shape (None, 32) and another convolutional layer with shape (None, 16, 16, 32). The output should have a shape (None, 16, 16), which is actually a weighted sum of convolutional units.

I try to solve this by a Lambda layer. And I just introduce tf.einsum operation to calculate the weighted sum.

```
def product_sum(inputs):
    conv_layers = inputs[0]   #(None, 16, 16, 32)
    weights = inputs[1]       #(None, 32)
    result = tf.einsum('ijkl, il->ijk', conv_layers, weights) 
    return result

# merge two layers
conv_output = basic_model.get_layer(last_conv_layer).output 
weight_output = basic_model.get_layer(weights_layer).output
weight_sum_ = Lambda(product_sum)
result = weight_sum([conv_output, weight_output])
model = Model(inputs=[basic_model.input], outputs=[result])
```

I suppose it works, but got an error inside tf.einsum: 
"ValueError: Indices have incorrect format: ijkl, il-> ijk".

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
merged = concatenate([layer1, layer2, ..., layerN])
```

Replace the *layersN* by the name of your own layers.

I've already developed something like this. Take a [look here](https://github.com/anjosma/sentiment-analysis_brazil-elections-2018/blob/master/models.py).

Comment: Thanks. But actually, you misunderstand my question. I want to merge layers with different output shape, which is not covered by 'concatenate'.

Comment: Did you try [this?](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/26942/concat-mode-can-only-merge-layers-with-matching-output-shapes-except-for-the-c)